# What is the best way to manage screen for 3.5, 4.0, 4.7 and 5.5 Inch screen iPhones of iOS 8 in Xcode designing mode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xib, iphone-6

Can anyone suggest what is the best way to manage iOS App for all size iPhones specially with UI design mostly via designing mode.

Previously with universal app we could manage XIBs by using same XIB name for iPhone and iPad screens but postfix ~ipad in iPad XIB name. For e.g.: (1) MyList.xib for iPhone (2) MyList~iPad.xib for iPad.

So, Is there any way to do screen management is such easy way for iOS 8 different size screens?

If single XIB can work for all screen sizes then it will be great too.